# Upgrade Symfony CMF to newset and css content-type issue

Tags: css, symfony, upgrade, symfony-cmf

I have problem with upgrading my symfony cmf aplication. My composer looks like:
http://pastebin.com/yhm6QVGx

after successful composer update I have css error like on [image: mime type problems with css files - IMHO there should be 404 error]

You can notice that request is /static/bundles/sonataadmin/bootstrap/...
but there is no folder called bootstrap
[image: My folder missed bootstrap]

also when I click on this file in network tab - there are no content:
[image]
<sub>(source: [scaleengine.net](https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/c46c7e2b0b63e7003b34ce5b238a3556.png))</sub>

below is full http header description:
[image]

What Should I do to continue my work?

Comment: Did you try installing the assets and assetic?

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a configuration issue with the FOSRestBundle. you need to add a rule like the following:
https://github.com/symfony-cmf/cmf-sandbox/blob/master/app/config/config.yml#L355